# Spring Batch - not processing all steps

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Sping Batch job with 8 steps that synchronizes 2 databases. The job runs in a Docker container on Apache Mesos. It has been running fine for a very long time until last month when I started to see that the last 4 steps are not being processed.

What I can see from the H2 database is that these 4 steps are being executed and completed everytime, but sometimes without any processing:

[BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPc4y.png)

As you can see from the image above STEP_EXECUTION_ID 5-8 are COMPLETED, but with READ_COUNT = 0 (a.k.a. an unsuccessfull run), while STEP_EXECUTION_ID 13-16 are COMPLETED with thousands of READ_COUNT (a.k.a. a successfull run).

Then again today STEP_EXECUTION_ID 21-24 are COMPLETED with READ_COUNT = 0.

This behaviour occurs totally in random, without any errors or any kind of signs why so. Therefore I need your help with figuring it out. Any help is deeply appreciated!

I have tried to increase the RAM and CPU, running on a different slave on mesos, running different ubuntu version 14, 16, 21 nothing seems to affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You did not share what these steps are doing, but it could be that their input is empty for those executions (like an empty file, table, etc therefore, read.count = 0).

In those cases, you can make the step fail with a listener, see documentation here: [Handling Step Completion When No Input is Found](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound)